# undefined reference to 'ff_put_pixels_clamped_mmx'

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, mingw, msys2, mingw-w64

I have a windows 8.1 64 bit, intel i7.
I am trying to build ffmpeg dynamic libraries (dll) from sources, version 3.2.4 For that, I cloned ffmpeg git repository, and checked out tag n3.2.4
I installed mingw64 in my windows 8.1, opened a mingw64 shell.
I ran "configure" command before building, with the following switches:

```
./configure --prefix=ffmpeg/ --disable-gpl --disable-nonfree --enable-shared --disable-static --disable-doc  --disable-yasm --disable-debug --disable-network
```

On some point, in the link phase, it exits with these ld errors:

```
WINDRES libswresample/swresampleres.o
GEN     libswresample/libswresample.ver
LD      libswresample/swresample-2.dll
sed -e "s/ @[^ ]*//" libswresample/swresample-2.orig.def > libswresample/swresample-2.def; dlltool -m i386:x86-64 -d libswresample/swresample-2.def -l libswresample/swresample.lib -D swresample-2.dll
LD      libavcodec/avcodec-57.dll
libavcodec/x86/simple_idct.o: In function `ff_simple_idct_put_mmx':
C:\GitRepos\ffmpeg/libavcodec/x86/simple_idct.c:911: undefined reference to `ff_put_pixels_clamped_mmx'
C:\GitRepos\ffmpeg/libavcodec/x86/simple_idct.c:911:(.text+0x1fb0): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `ff_put_pixels_clamped_mmx'
libavcodec/x86/simple_idct.o: In function `ff_simple_idct_add_mmx':
C:\GitRepos\ffmpeg/libavcodec/x86/simple_idct.c:916: undefined reference to `ff_add_pixels_clamped_mmx'
C:\GitRepos\ffmpeg/libavcodec/x86/simple_idct.c:916:(.text+0x1fe0): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `ff_add_pixels_clamped_mmx'
libavcodec/x86/simple_idct.o: In function `ff_simple_idct_put_sse2':
C:\GitRepos\ffmpeg/libavcodec/x86/simple_idct.c:921: undefined reference to `ff_put_pixels_clamped_sse2'
C:\GitRepos\ffmpeg/libavcodec/x86/simple_idct.c:921:(.text+0x2010): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `ff_put_pixels_clamped_sse2'
libavcodec/x86/simple_idct.o: In function `ff_simple_idct_add_sse2':
C:\GitRepos\ffmpeg/libavcodec/x86/simple_idct.c:926: undefined reference to `ff_add_pixels_clamped_sse2'
C:\GitRepos\ffmpeg/libavcodec/x86/simple_idct.c:926:(.text+0x2040): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `ff_add_pixels_clamped_sse2'
```

Found out that adding -mcmodel=large switch as suggested in some places should fix it. 
After I added it, I only left with the "undefined reference" errors, which I have a feeling that is related to 64/32 bit issues:

```
GEN     libswresample/libswresample.ver
LD      libswresample/swresample-2.dll
sed -e "s/ @[^ ]*//" libswresample/swresample-2.orig.def > libswresample/swresample-2.def; dlltool -m i386:x86-64 -d libswresample/swresample-2.def -l libswresample/swresample.lib -D swresample-2.dll
LD      libavcodec/avcodec-57.dll
libavcodec/x86/simple_idct.o:simple_idct.c:(.rdata$.refptr.ff_add_pixels_clamped_sse2[.refptr.ff_add_pixels_clamped_sse2]+0x0): undefined reference to `ff_add_pixels_clamped_sse2'
libavcodec/x86/simple_idct.o:simple_idct.c:(.rdata$.refptr.ff_put_pixels_clamped_sse2[.refptr.ff_put_pixels_clamped_sse2]+0x0): undefined reference to `ff_put_pixels_clamped_sse2'
libavcodec/x86/simple_idct.o:simple_idct.c:(.rdata$.refptr.ff_add_pixels_clamped_mmx[.refptr.ff_add_pixels_clamped_mmx]+0x0): undefined reference to `ff_add_pixels_clamped_mmx'
libavcodec/x86/simple_idct.o:simple_idct.c:(.rdata$.refptr.ff_put_pixels_clamped_mmx[.refptr.ff_put_pixels_clamped_mmx]+0x0): undefined reference to `ff_put_pixels_clamped_mmx'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [library.mak:94: libavcodec/avcodec-57.dll] Error 1
```

Please help,
thanks

Answer (score 1):

As per `configure`:

```
mmx_deps="x86"
mmxext_deps="mmx"
sse_deps="mmxext"
sse2_deps="sse"
sse3_deps="sse2"
ssse3_deps="sse3"
sse4_deps="ssse3"
sse42_deps="sse4"
...
mmx_external_deps="yasm"
```

So, the whole cascade depends on `yasm` but that's been disabled via switch.

Comment: Thanks! It seems that was the issue. But, from some reason, my application that is linked with it can't run, and throws the following error:  the program can't start because libiconv-2.dll is missing from your computer

Answer (score 1):

You tagged the question with `msys2`.  If you are really using MSYS2, I would recommend using the precompiled ffmpeg packages provided by the MSYS2 developers, which you can install with pacman:

```
pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-ffmpeg mingw-w64-i686-ffmpeg
```

If you really need to build it yourself from source, you can see how the package was built by the MSYS2 developers here:

https://github.com/Alexpux/MINGW-packages/tree/master/mingw-w64-ffmpeg

Comment: Thanks, but I need to build a specific version - n3.2.4